# LaTeX: Use command argument in conditional?

Tags: macros, conditionals, comparison

I'm in the process of writing a command that outputs a certain text only if its argument is a nonzero number. I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
\newcommand{mycommand}[1]{
\if{#1 != 0}
Some text, because it's nonzero
\else
Some other text, because it's zero
\fi
}

\mycommand{0}
\mycommand{1}
```

And get the output:

```
Some other text, because it's zero
Some text, because it's nonzero
```

I'm running into trouble getting the conditional right, though - I'm not sure that LaTeX is treating `#1` like an integer to be checked (or even if that's the right syntax for not-equals - I wasn't able to find a ton of information on integer conditionals). How might I go about writing this conditional?

Comment: You should end the lines with `%` otherwise you'll get additional spaces in your text. Try `foo\mycommand{0}bar` with the working code from Martin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
\ifnum0=#1\relax
  Some other text, because it's zero
\else
  Some text, because it's nonzero
\fi
}
```

Or with the `ifthen` package:

```
\ifthenelse{0=#1}{%
    Some other text, because it's zero
}{%
    Some text, because it's nonzero
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For someone who might be looking to do this in ConTeXt, the equivalent solution is

```
\define[1]\mycommand%
  {\doifelse{#1}{0}
       {Some text, because it is zero}
       {Some other text, because it is not zero}}
```

See the wiki page on [branching](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions) for more details.